# How to perform padding operation if the kernel stride is greater than the input shape dimensions in case of Maxpooling

Tags: caffe

I am trying to perform Maxpooling operation in caffe.

Input size is 6 x 6 x 1 x 1024 whereas the kernel size is 7 x 7.

Am i supposed to do padding inorder to perform MaxPooling.

Comment: are you using `matcaffe`? the order of your input dimensions seems odd.

Comment: In your case you might want to do global_pool reducing to 1x1 blob.

Comment: @shai.....i am not using matcaffe ......padding is not required in my case??

Comment: you might need padding. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am using a pretrained model in caffe. input image size is 6x6 but whereas kernel size is 7x7 and while calculating output shape using the formula : (W - F)/2 + 1 ....i am getting 0 which i strange....i suspect that i am supposed to do padding but i am not sure...struck with this for a long time......

Answer (score 0):

First, you haven't specified the stride; the kernel dimensions are 7x7, larger than your input, but that's the size, not the stride.  `Stride` is how far you move between iterations, such as shifting 2 pixels (which effectively halves the size of the output).

You probably want to pad so that the center of the kernel (element (3, 3) with 0-based indexing) can be over each pixel of your input.  This means that you need a 3-pixel pad ( (7-1)/2 ) in each direction.

Is that what you needed?